# ViewState becomes null after postback

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I have trying to get the JavaScript Calendar Pikaday to work in my net application I am developing.  I want to pass a value from the textbox(which when clicked on, displays a JS calendar to select a day. This then becomes a variable to send in to sql and pull a stored procedure) I have to format the text to be able to get sent through the database, as the control for the sqldatasource in ASP is tied to the textbox. For whatever reason, Pikaday will display the day before in the Textbox even though the correct date was sent and queries the database to update my gridview.

I was trying to store the variable in a ViewState and on Pageload, change the value of the textbox. The ViewState is always null even with the EnableViewState on the page and textbox. What am I doing wrong? ViewState works in the click event, but because the Textbox is the control, I can't do that.

```
 public partial class WebForm3 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //Used to change the color of the button "Export to excel"
        string hex = "#5CB85C";
        Button2.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml(hex);
        Button2.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            if (dateFull != null)
            {
                Button1.Text = dateFull;
            }
            if (DropDownList2.SelectedIndex > 0)
            {
                //changes the GridView by the program filter
                changeByProgram();
            }
            dateFull = null;


        }
    }
    public string dateFull
    {
        get
        {
            string text = (string)ViewState["date"];
            if (text != null)
                return text;
            else
                return string.Empty;
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["date"] = value;
        }
    }
    private void changeByDate()
    {
        if (TextBox2.Text.Equals(""))
        {
            GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource1";
            dateFull = null;
        }
        if (TextBox2.Text != "")
        {
            String date = TextBox2.Text;
            dateFull = date;
            string dayOfWeek = date.Substring(0, 3);
            date = date.Substring(3);
            string month = date.Substring(1, 3);
            string day = date.Substring(5, 2);
            string year = date.Substring(8, 4);
            switch (month)
            {
                case "Jan":
                    month = "01";
                    break;
                case "Feb":
                    month = "02";
                    break;
                case "Mar":
                    month = "03";
                    break;
                case "Apr":
                    month = "04";
                    break;
                case "May":
                    month = "05";
                    break;
                case "Jun":
                    month = "06";
                    break;
                case "Jul":
                    month = "07";
                    break;
                case "Aug":
                    month = "08";
                    break;
                case "Sep":
                    month = "09";
                    break;
                case "Oct":
                    month = "10";
                    break;
                case "Nov":
                    month = "11";
                    break;
                case "Dec":
                    month = "12";
                    break;
                default:
                    break;

            }
            date = year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
            TextBox2.Text = date;
            var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestAdamConnectionString"].ToString());
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("datePullScrap", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", date);
            conn.Open();
            GridView1.DataSourceID = "SqlDataSource4";
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
     protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        changeByDate();
        //Button1.Text = (string)ViewState["date"];
    }
     <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="RawScrapData.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication4.WebForm3" EnableEventValidation="true" EnableViewState="True" ViewStateMode="Enabled" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
     <link href="~/Content/StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"     media="screen" runat="server" />
     <script src="../pikaday.js"></script>
     <link href="../css/triangle.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <link href="../css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <link href="../css/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet" />
     <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
         <div class="auto-style1">
         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Font-Size="Medium" Text="Datepicker:" Font-Names="Consolas" ></asp:Label>  &nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Submit" />
                    <br />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" ViewStateMode="Enabled" EnableViewState="True" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox>
                    <script> type = "text/javascript"
                        var picker = new Pikaday(
                            {

                                field: document.getElementById('TextBox2'),
                                format: 'YYYY/MM/DD',
                                firstDay: 0,
                                minDate: new Date('1990-01-01'),
                                maxDate: new Date('2020-12-31'),
                                yearRange: [1990, 2020],
                                numberOfMonths: 1,
                                theme: 'dark-theme'
                            });

                    </script>
             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource4" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:TestAdamConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="datePullScrap" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                  <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox2" Name="Date" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
                  </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could be due to the order in which you are handling the data.  Maybe check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555152/net-viewstate-in-page-lifecycle)

Comment: Can we look at the markup for the front page? Should your TextBox2 be set to autopostback = true?

Comment: I added HTML for your viewing pleasure.  I tried the AutoPostBack and it just makes the page reload again and again when I select the date without clicking the Submit button.