# Keeping ViewState of page after PostBack Refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a drop down list with the list items created in the code behind. ddlFill(). Pretty simple and does the job. It's populated with the current month and some months ahead. I use this drop down as a selection to fill a Gridview. When this drop down index changes, it changes a hidden field value and a corresponding query to fill the gridview. All this works as it should. Within the gridview I have another dropdown list and a button. Both submit the selected row to a database. That also works fine. The problem is, each time one of these rows submits to the database, it causes a post back and it resets the whole page. It resets the drop down list to the first list item . I.E. I change the drop down list to index 4 for example. Which would be April in this case. If I submit a row to the db, the page refreshes and goes back to index 0 .. January in this case. How do I keep it from resetting this way and maintaining the position I was in when I submitted the row?

I have tried a few different options. I've tried session states. hidden field value changes. Nothing seems to work. It either does not perform the post back therefore never submits to the db or it does the post back, submits correctly, then resets the whole page. Including resetting the hiddenfield value back to 0

```
  /* This is up in Page load. */

       if (Session["pageStatus"] != null)
        {
            if (Session["pageStatus"].ToString() == "Loaded")
            {
                hf2.Value = "Loaded";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            hf2.Value = "New";
        }

        if (Session["selectedMonth"] != null)
        {
            hf1.Value = Session["selectedMonth"].ToString();
        }

        if (ViewState["button_was_clicked"] != null)
        {
            ddlFill();
            StyleDDL();
        }

        lblTestlabel.Text = hf2.Value;
        AddAttributes();


        ShowMonth();
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            btnReviewCurrentMonth_OnClick(sender, e);
            ddlFill();
            StyleDDL();
        }
```

---

```
private void ddlFill()
    {



            string a, b, c, d, e, f;
            a = "0"; 
            b = "1";
            c = "2";
            d = "3";
            e = "4";
            f = "5";

            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem(ReturnMonth(a))); // A blank object call and the ReturnMonth Method fill the list items.
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(1, new ListItem(ReturnMonth(b)));
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(2, new ListItem(ReturnMonth(c)));
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(3, new ListItem(ReturnMonth(d)));
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(4, new ListItem(ReturnMonth(e)));
            DropDownList1.Items.Insert(5, new ListItem(ReturnMonth(f)));

      /* These were for various testing options to get it to maintain the 
         state */
        hf2.Value = "Loaded";
        Session["pageStatus"] = "Loaded";
        DropDownList1.SelectedIndex = Int32.Parse(hf1.Value);
    }
```

My goal is to maintain the state of the page after the submission to the db occurs.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555152/net-viewstate-in-page-lifecycle

Comment: I believe that issue is caused because `ddlFill` method is called on postback. ASP.NET controls retain their states on postback by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this question difficult to ask because it had so many moving parts. The ddlFill() method wasn't the problem. All it litterally did was fill list items. Those corresponding Selected Index values would change when selected and based on those values I would assign a different value to a hidden field. Which was then used as SqlDataSource control variable and would bring back GridView data based on that control value.

A drop down list within the gridview was used to select and submit the indexed row to a SQL DB. At the end of that code I was refreshing the page. It needed a refresh to properly submit and bring back a fresh Gridview with the previously submitted row now gone. That was the problem. When it refreshed, it changed the hidden field value to 0 and reset everything back. So, here is what I did.

```
 //This method controls the Drop Down List change event. Underwriter change. 
    protected void DropDownList1_OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)ddl.Parent.Parent;
        int idx = row.RowIndex;

        GridView1.SelectedIndex = idx;

        string Client = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[0].Text;//Client Name
        string NewUw = ddl.Text.ToString();
        int UniqCNT = new Int32();
        UniqCNT = Int32.Parse(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[1].Text.ToString()); //UniqClient */
        string ExpPolicyNums = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        int Ub = Int32.Parse(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[10].Text);//UniqBroker
        DateTime ExperationDate = DateTime.Parse(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[6].Text); //ExpDate


        string Company = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[7].Text; //Company issuer
        string Broker = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[8].Text;  //Broker_Name
        string Premium = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[3].Text; //Premiums
        string TotalPremium = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[4].Text; //Total premiums
        string Reviewed = "No"; //Updates the DB and shows that it hasn't been reviewed by the Message Creator
                                //DateCreated gets inserted when record is created 
        string InsertedBy = Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.Substring(Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name.LastIndexOf(@"\") + 1);

        DateTime dateUpDated = DateTime.Now; //Inserts a dateUpdated record

        string query = "INSERT INTO [GTU_Apps].[dbo].[Reviewed_Renewal_Policy] (UniqClient, Client, [Expiring_Policies], Premiums, TotalPremium, UniqBroker, ExpDate, NewUw, Company, Broker_Name,  Reviewed, DateUpDated, InsertedBy) " +
            "VALUES (@UniqCNT, @Client, @ExpPolicyNums, @Premium, @TotalPremium, @Ub, @ExperationDate, @NewUw, @Company, @Broker,  @Reviewed, @dateUpDated, @InsertedBy)";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=GTU-BDE01;Initial Catalog=GTU_Apps;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
            {
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UniqCNT", UniqCNT);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Client", Client);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpPolicyNums", ExpPolicyNums);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Premium", Premium);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalPremium", TotalPremium);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ub", Ub);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExperationDate", ExperationDate);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewUw", NewUw);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", Company);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Broker", Broker);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reviewed", Reviewed);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateUpDated", dateUpDated);
                comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@InsertedBy", InsertedBy);
                conn.Open();
                comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        GridView1.DataBind();  
        GridView1.SelectedIndex = -1;
        int index = DropDownList1.SelectedIndex;
        ConfirmIndex(index);
        //End(sender, e);
    }
```

Using the DataBind worked. It only refreshed the Gridview. Which was really what I needed. I had other items that were refreshing too. That's why those calls below it are there. If someone sees this, hopefully it will help.